# Are my answers to this probability question correct?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Here is the full question:

A city installs 2017 electric lamps for street lighting. These lamps have a mean burning life of 1000 hours with a standard deviation of 200 hours. The normal distribution is a close approximation to this case.

(a) What is the probability that a lamp will fail in the first 600 burning hours?
(b) What is the probability that a lamp will fail between 800 and 1200 burning hours?
(c) How many lamps are expected to fail between 800 and 1200 burning hours?
(d) What is the probability that a lamp will burn for exactly 800 hours?

**My Answer:**
(a) 2.28%
(b) 68.26%
(c) 1377 lamps
(d) 34.13%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standardizing it to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1 then

(a) 600 burning hours is $-2\sigma$ or $-2$. Probability that any bulb fails during this time is $2.28%$(From the table).

(b) 800 to 1200 is $-\sigma$ to $\sigma$. The probability that any one bulb fails is 68.27

(c) Using the result in (b) we can say the probability that k bulbs fail $P(k)$ is $$P(k) = \binom{2017}{k}(0.6827)^k(0.3173)^{2017-k}$$ and so the expected value is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2017}kP(k)=np=2017\times0.6827=1377$$

(d) For it to burn exactly 800 hours it means that it fails in $(800-dt,800)$ where $dt \rightarrow 0$. This probability is $0$. **Probability at a single point in a continuous distribution is $0$.**